# Is it ok to do single instances when testing with phpunit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Is it ok to create a single object instance and storing it in a **private** or **static** property?

I mean, most of the examples out there will create one instance per test. In the other hand, this seems like a waste of resources to me.

Here is an example:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
    private $obj;

    public function testFoo()
    {
        $this->assertEquals($this->obj->foo(), 'something');
    }


    public function testBar()
    {
        $this->assertEquals($this->obj->bar(), 'something else');
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->obj = new MyClass();
    }
}
```

Could it be considered a bad practice or cause any unexpected behaviour (from the testing point of view)?

Comment: you could override the `setUp()` and `tearDown()`methods in order to configure the initial state of the object under test (instead of the constructor) as described [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) in the doc

Comment: @Matteo Good to know! people doesn't mention that very often in their articles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it's not a good practice. What you want to avoid is a unit test that wrongly passes or fails because of state carried over from a different test.

Consider this contrived example:

```
public function testSet()
{
    $this->obj->setValue(4);
    $this->assertEquals(4, $this->obj->getValue());
}

public function testAdd()
{
    $this->obj->add(4);
    $this->assertEquals(8, $this->obj->getValue());
}
```

There is no guarantee that PHPUnit runs tests in a particular order, so this will fail if it decides to run testAdd before testSet.

A unit test should preferably set up all the state it needs in isolation and then test only the specific case being tested.

There are things you might set up as shared resources in a test case, such as database connections, but these are typically external and not part of the system under test.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the setUp and tearDown methods, which are designed for what the OP is using the constructor for

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that one should not override TestCase::__construct (and not accept all parameters and pass them to the parent constructor).